# Usage of “as” in a different way

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

> Don't change a character that Gene intentionally created as straight.

This is the sentence I saw on the internet. Can “as” be used  to modifie adjectives . I mean Can I say ;

> You must raise our children as respectful to other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'as' must proceed a noun.

In the example you provide of:

> Don't change a character that Gene intentionally created as straight.

While 'straight' is not specifically a noun it is implied that the writer means 'as (a) straight (person)'

The second example grammatically works but is hard to read because you would be implying 'You must raise our children as (people who are) respectful to other people'.

You could say 'You must raise our children as respectful', but its not clear that they should be respectful towards anything. I would be more inclined to say 'You must raise our children to be respectful'.

Comment: Thanks a lot . By the way Is title grammatically corrrect ? I mean Can I use “usage” and  in a way” together? I realized it after writing .

Comment: @languagelearner yes the title is correct. I would say that "Different ways to use 'as'" sounds more suitable for your question though :).